# PascalCase or kebab-case usage in Vue's DOM content?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to understand the vue documentation on components. I came across this paragraph in the documentation:

```
If you are authoring your templates directly in a DOM (e.g. as the content of a native <template> element), the 
template will be subject to the browser's native HTML parsing behavior. 
In such cases, you will need to use kebab-case and explicit closing tags for components:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<!-- if this template is written in the DOM -->
<button-counter></button-counter>
<button-counter></button-counter>
<button-counter></button-counter>
```

I don't fully understand what this means. In my project I am able to use pascal case OR kebab case without problems. Why does the documentation say `In such cases, you will need to use kebab-case`?

What case is it referring to?

In my template, I can do `<MyComponent/>` and I can also do `<my-component></mycomponent>` so can someone explain when and why I would ever **NEED** to use kebab case?

Here is the [Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, all the limitations listed here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dom-template-parsing-caveats

Are only for the cases when you use Vue via a CDN. You are probably using SFC files, in that situation you don't really need to worry about those limitations.

Keep in mind that consistency is quite important tho, so try to not mix both of them (stick to only one form). AFAIK, most Vue devs are using kebab-case (myself too).

There is no hard argument for one or the other, there are benefits and downsides to both. Quite some answers regarding this kind of style guide are detailed here: https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#component-name-casing-in-templates

Comment: There are several scenarios in which a comp may use a DOM-based template. Actually CDN doesn't affect this, as long as templates are defined as strings

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah it's just more likely to be the case when used outside of a build system I guess but it's not always a blocker neither. What does it refer to so? Injected content from a `textContent` used in a component for example?

Comment: Yes, this, and also https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/inline-template-attribute.html#option-1-use-script-tag , and https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#mounting-the-app

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can use either kebab-case or PascalCase. But it's strongly recommended using kebab inside DOM template in order to have syntax consistency with other html tags.

Please refer to official Vue style guide:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Component-name-casing-in-templates-strongly-recommended

Comment: Consistency is not the reason, it's a byproduct, the sentence starts with "Also"

Answer (score 2):

In Vue 3 the generally recommended way is `PascalCase`.

> PascalCase names are valid JavaScript identifiers. This makes it
> easier to import and register components in JavaScript. It also helps
> IDEs with auto-completion.
>
> `<PascalCase />` makes it more obvious that this is a Vue component
> instead of a native HTML element in templates. It also differentiates
> Vue components from custom elements (web components).
>
> This is the recommended style when working with SFC or string
> templates. However, as discussed in in-DOM Template Parsing Caveats,
> PascalCase tags are not usable in in-DOM templates.

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#component-name-casing

Comment: More detailed answers depending of the context (several casing expanded on that page): https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html

Comment: I have everything in kebab-case because I converted the whole project from vue 2 to vue 3. Is there a tool to convert everything to PascalCase?