# kebab-case in MDB components for Vue

Tags: vue.js, material-design, coding-style, vuejs3

The Vue documentation ([here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#component-name-casing)) states that you need to use kebab-case to connect components in the DOM...
I use [Material Design for Bootstrap 5 & Vue 3](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/) and the components are written using PascaleCase (although kebab-case is used for Bootstrap 4).

Question: based on the Vue documentation, is it necessary to connect components using kebab-case:

```js
components: {
  ...
  "mdb-tab": MDBTab,
  ...
},
```

or leave it as it is, which will be strange since I connect my components via kebab-case:

```html
...
<my-first-component />
<MDBTab></MDBTab>
<my-last-component />
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no huge differences between using

```html
<my-cool-component></my-cool-component>
<MyCoolComponent />
<my-cool-component /> <!-- this one is less correct HTML-wise but still works thanks to compiler -->
```

Simply try to stick to one convention.

To get more details on the little differences, you can read the [style guide](https://vuejs.org/style-guide/rules-strongly-recommended.html#component-name-casing-in-templates) and use kebab-case if you want to avoid some [minor limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73789084/8816585).